# Is there a formulaic relation between the accuracy of the approximation and the number of terms used in the binomial expansion

Tags: approximation, binomial-theorem, negative-binomial

So I am aware that with the increase in number of terms the approximation becomes more accurate but I wished to know if I have a binomial of the form say,

$$ f(x) = (1-Rx)^{-n}$$

where $R$ is a real number and $n$ is a natural number,
then is there a relation using which I can determine the accuracy of my approximation.
Say, the above $f(x)$ is expanded as below,

$$f(x) = 1 + ax + bx^2 + cx^3 + ... $$
$$b(x) = 1 + ax + bx^2$$

then, does there exist some formula or relation using which I can conclude that if I take the first three terms of $f(x)$ and find a value at $1/10R$, then,
$b(1/10R)$ will only be accurate upto the first decimal value of $f(1/10R)$.

I have tried it on some integer values and that seemed to be the case but I think it is just the bias in my data. So, I would like to know if there indeed exists some formula or intuitive way to calculate the accuracy of the approximation.

I also posted the question on MO:- https://mathoverflow.net/questions/448831/is-there-a-formulaic-relation-between-the-accuracy-of-the-approximation-and-the

Comment: Since your power series converges for every $x$ such that $|x|<1/|R|$ and you need to evaluate the truncation error at $x={1\over 10R}$, you can apply the result I gave in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2815449/how-to-bound-the-remainder-of-a-truncated-power-series/2816260#2816260). It is possibly not sharp since it applies to *all power series* inside their convergence disk, but it is quite explicit, and by using the same method you can get a sharp estimate for your power series.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I'll try to see if something can be worked out.